# fail2ban errors on Fedora 25: WARNING Mutliline regex set for jail '%s' but maxlines not greater than 1, ERROR No 'host' group in '<mdre-<mode>>'

Tags: fedora, fail2ban

I see these errors with a recent sshd.conf file. Is there a reason for the `mdre-normal` being set to nothing?

```
2017-07-10 10:51:42,218 fail2ban.filter         [10436]: WARNING Mutliline regex set for jail '%s' but maxlines not greater than 1
2017-07-10 10:51:42,231 fail2ban.filter         [10436]: WARNING Mutliline regex set for jail '%s' but maxlines not greater than 1
2017-07-10 10:51:42,245 fail2ban.filter         [10436]: WARNING Mutliline regex set for jail '%s' but maxlines not greater than 1
2017-07-10 10:51:42,255 fail2ban.filter         [10436]: ERROR   No 'host' group in '<mdre-<mode>>'
2017-07-10 10:51:42,255 fail2ban.transmitter    [10436]: WARNING Command ['set', 'sshd', 'addfailregex', '<mdre-<mode>>'] has failed. Received RegexException("No 'host' group in '<mdre-<mode>>'",)
2017-07-10 10:51:42,260 fail2ban.jail           [10436]: INFO    Creating new jail 'sshd-ddos'
```

unban errors:

```
2017-07-10 10:50:11,097 fail2ban.action         [3653]: ERROR   firewall-cmd --remove-source=185.56.82.23 --zone=drop && firewall-cmd --remove-source=185.56.82.23 --zone=drop --permanent -- stdout: b'success\n'
2017-07-10 10:50:11,097 fail2ban.action         [3653]: ERROR   firewall-cmd --remove-source=185.56.82.23 --zone=drop && firewall-cmd --remove-source=185.56.82.23 --zone=drop --permanent -- stderr: b''
2017-07-10 10:50:11,097 fail2ban.action         [3653]: ERROR   firewall-cmd --remove-source=185.56.82.23 --zone=drop && firewall-cmd --remove-source=185.56.82.23 --zone=drop --permanent -- killed with SIGTERM (return code: -15)
2017-07-10 10:50:11,098 fail2ban.actions        [3653]: ERROR   Failed to execute unban jail 'recidive' action 'custom-firewalld' info '{'ip': '185.56.82.23', 'failures': 5, 'time': 1499270396.6778345, 'matches': '2016-12-28 14:30:25,831 fail2ban.actions        [1884]
: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 185.56.82.232016-12-28 15:37:59,825 fail2ban.actions        [1884]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 185.56.82.232016-12-28 16:45:28,589 fail2ban.actions        [1884]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 185.56.82.232016-12-28 17:52:37,468 fail2ban.actions        [1884]: NOTIC
E  [sshd] Ban 185.56.82.232016-12-28 18:59:56,325 fail2ban.actions        [1884]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 185.56.82.23'}': Error unbanning 185.56.82.23
```

cat sshd.conf I see that `mdre-normal =` is blank.

```
# Fail2Ban obsolete multiline example resp. test filter (previously sshd.conf)
#

[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf

[DEFAULT]

_daemon = sshd

[Definition]

cmnfailre = ^%(__prefix_line_sl)s[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error|failed) for .* from <HOST>( via \S+)?\s*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sUser not known to the underlying authentication module for .* from <HOST>\s*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sFailed \S+ for (?P<cond_inv>invalid user )?(?P<user>(?P<cond_user>\S+)|(?(cond_inv)(?:(?! from ).)*?|[^:]+)) from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s(?: ssh\d*)?(?(cond_user): |(?:(?:(?! from ).)*)$)
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sROOT LOGIN REFUSED.* FROM <HOST>\s*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)s[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .*? from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s\s*$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers\s*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because listed in DenyUsers\s*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not in any group\s*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)srefused connect from \S+ \(<HOST>\)\s*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sReceived disconnect from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s:\s*3: .*: Auth fail%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because a group is listed in DenyGroups\s*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups\s*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)spam_unix\(sshd:auth\):\s+authentication failure;\s*logname=\S*\s*uid=\d*\s*euid=\d*\s*tty=\S*\s*ruser=\S*\s*rhost=<HOST>\s.*%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_sl)s(error: )?maximum authentication attempts exceeded for .* from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s(?: ssh\d*)? \[preauth\]$
         ^%(__prefix_line_ml1)sUser .+ not allowed because account is locked%(__prefix_line_ml2)sReceived disconnect from <HOST>: 11: .+%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_ml1)sDisconnecting: Too many authentication failures(?: for .+?)?%(__suff)s%(__prefix_line_ml2)sConnection closed by <HOST>%(__suff)s$
         ^%(__prefix_line_ml1)sConnection from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s%(__prefix_line_ml2)sDisconnecting: Too many authentication failures(?: for .+?)?%(__suff)s$

mdre-normal =

mdre-ddos =  ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sDid not receive identification string from <HOST>%(__suff)s$
             ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sConnection reset by <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s%(__suff)s
             ^%(__prefix_line_ml1)sSSH: Server;Ltype: (?:Authname|Version|Kex);Remote: <HOST>-\d+;[A-Z]\w+:.*%(__prefix_line_ml2)sRead from socket failed: Connection reset by peer%(__suff)s$

mdre-extra = ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sReceived disconnect from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s:\s*14: No supported authentication methods available%(__suff)s$
             ^%(__prefix_line_sl)sUnable to negotiate with <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s: no matching (?:cipher|key exchange method) found.
             ^%(__prefix_line_ml1)sConnection from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s%(__prefix_line_ml2)sUnable to negotiate a (?:cipher|key exchange method)%(__suff)s$

mdre-aggressive = %(mdre-ddos)s
                  %(mdre-extra)s

failregex = %(cmnfailre)s
            <mdre-<mode>>

# Parameter "mode": normal (default), ddos, extra or aggressive (combines all)
# Usage example (for jail.local):
#   [sshd]
#   mode = extra
#   # or another jail (rewrite filter parameters of jail):
#   [sshd-aggressive]
#   filter = sshd[mode=aggressive]
#
mode = normal

ignoreregex = 

# "maxlines" is number of log lines to buffer for multi-line regex searches
maxlines = 10

journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd

datepattern = {^LN-BEG}

# DEV Notes:
#
#   "Failed \S+ for .*? from <HOST>..." failregex uses non-greedy catch-all because
#   it is coming before use of <HOST> which is not hard-anchored at the end as well,
#   and later catch-all's could contain user-provided input, which need to be greedily
#   matched away first.
#
# Author: Cyril Jaquier, Yaroslav Halchenko, Petr Voralek, Daniel Black
```

cat custom-firewalld.conf [based on this suggestion](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1474#issuecomment-272659488).

```
[INCLUDES]
before  =

[Definition]
actionstart =
actionstop =
actioncheck =

actionban = firewall-cmd --add-source=<ip> --zone=drop && firewall-cmd --add-source=<ip> --zone=drop --permanent
actionunban = firewall-cmd --remove-source=<ip> --zone=drop && firewall-cmd --remove-source=<ip> --zone=drop --permanent

[Init]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I used a sshd.conf file from the newer 0.10 Fail2ban, [which is not 100% compatible](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1823). [This is](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.9/config/filter.d/sshd.conf) the correct version for 0.95.